# Javascript Make div appear from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope my question makes sense, but what im trying to do is: show a div by transition. Meaning i want the div to slowly appear from top to bottom or from left to right, almost like a fade. Is this possible with either javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, if i understand u need something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/e5BuX/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cube").animate({left:"400px",opacity:"1"},2000);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the closest thing is the jQuery slideUp() or slideDown() methods. they are not a fade exactly, but like I said, probably the closest thing ( I am not a JavaScript/jQuery expert though).

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp) is a site that demonstrates how they look.

EDIT: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp) are some other good examples of custom animations you can do with the animate() method

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Its possible with vanilla javascript and [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) but it can also be done entirely css3 transition & animate. Take a look [here for example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/)

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done only with css3. Here's a [rough ideea](http://jsfiddle.net/4f2hR/2/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="im-a-div animate-me im-hidden">
    <span class="center-me">I'm inside the div!</span>
</div>

<input id="show-the-div" type="button" value="Show div"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.im-a-div {
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 400px;
}

.im-hidden {
    margin-top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-me {
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1000ms 0s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1000ms 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1000ms 0s ease-in-out;
}
```